# AFD: CNAME/alias record is not currently detected

Tags: azure, subdomain

I am currently working with Azure Front Door to create sub domains for my websites

We have a (third party) wild card certificate for a website (bignose.com) and we want to create the subdomain pick.bignose.com.

I am using azure front door for this, since the application is run in an Azure Webservice
Azure Front Door Sub domain gives a CNAME error

Azure front door tells me to add a txt record in our DNS service (TransIP) so ive done that.

| Name | TTL | TYPE | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _dnsauth.pick.bignose.nl | 3600 | TXT | randomgiberish |

However, the domain state in Azure Front Door is still Pending.

I also see a message 'CNAME/alias record is not currently detected'.

Reading about the cname, I asume it means that I had to add a cname record for the subdomain. I cannot find the format for this record. So i tried something like this:

| Name | TTL | TYPE | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pick | 3600 | CNAME | @ |

but the message remains. I have very little experience with DNS settings so I feel like a toddler operating a nuclear reactor. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

UPDATE1:
I changed the cname record to use the frontdoor domain url:

| Name | TTL | TYPE | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pick | 3600 | CNAME | weird.front.door.url. |

And this got rid of the DNS state message. I still have the pending validation message however.